# Android: MediaScanner marks 3gp file with video/mp4 mimetype

Tags: mime-types, 3gp, android-mediascanner

I just noticed that MediaScanner marks 3gp file with video/mp4. I've searched about it in Google and found this [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.platform/4103). It is written there that,

> "The video camera marks videos that it creates with mime type
>   video/3gpp. This is the actual correct mime type for 3gp video.
>   The media scanner marks 3gp videos with the mime type video/mp4. It
>   could be argued that the media scanner should use the more specific
>   mime type of video/3gp, but technically 3gp is a kind of mp4, so it's
>   not exactly incorrect to use video/mp4."

If you notice the date it was posted is 2009-03-26. When I checked it again on Android 2.3.4 it is still the same. Is there any plan of having a more specific mimetype for 3gp in the future?

Thanks,
artsylar

Comment: Same problem in android 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've just edited the MPEG4Extractor.cpp to set the mimetype of 3gp files to audio/3gpp or video/3gpp instead of audio/mp4 or video/mp4.